# Why did the aliens leave as soon as the strike was called back in Arrival (2016)

Tags: plot-explanation, arrival

SPOILER ALERT: This was probably discussed before but if the Aliens did indeed come to pass on the 'gift' to humans, why did they leave as soon as the worldwide strike on their ships was called off? Did they just assume that the entire humankind will cooperate and pick up on what (they probably on were able to infer) Louise had learned?

What were they really hoping to achieve by passing on their gift to humans? Surely by the time they left only Louise seems to have actually learned to navigate time the way they do.

Aliens' premise seems really far fetched to me. Consider the two options

a.) Only Louise learned to use their weapon (language)- how are they sure humans 3000 years will return favor? Based on the future flashes towards the end, it still seems like Louise is still teaching all of this in her classes, meaning it's still at the very best an exotic skill, so aliens left sooner than they should've? Why did they leave if they're able to infer that humans won't learn the skill on a wide scale right away.

b.) Entire humankind will be able to navigate time- peaking into future and looking back into past the way Louise does. Did they really assess the implications of human race on this?

Comment: Welcome to the community. You are asking some very good questions here. Please consider breaking up your post so that you ask only one question (or group of *very* related questions) per post. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Comment: Apart from anything else, the movie makes it clear that Louise *wrote a whole book* on interpreting the alien language. So she is clearly no longer the only one who gets it. The aliens know this because they can see the future so their mission is accomplished.

Answer (score 3):

We don't know that Louise is the only one who learned the language to the point of her timeline being non-linear. The movie doesn't tell us anything about the other landing sites. It could be that other scientists learned the language also and therefore the aliens gave the gift and then left. 

 see [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63566/37722) for more information on that.

Even if not, it seems to be that China and America are the 2 superpowers involved in the movie and everyone seems to be revolving around their decisions regarding the aliens. Once the aliens saw that they were able to work together, they had no reason to continue their visit and left.